# ListView with dynamic pagination

Tags: gluon, gluon-mobile, javafxports, gluon-desktop

I need a ListView/CharmListView with dynamic pagination, loading dynamically from server. Is this possible?

My backend method already waits for start, page and limit url parameters.

Thanks!

Comment: Both ListView and CharmListView use an observable list of items, so whenever you change that list (from the backend, for instance), the control will refresh those changes. As for "pagination", the CharmListView has a configurable header that can be used to separate content based on some criteria, but after all the content will be added to the list. Pagination could be implemented on top of it, so you can have a ListView/CharmListView added to each page.

Comment: Ok @JoséPereda thank you, I am going to try!!!